# next.js, Intercepting Routes (.) (..) issue

Tags: next.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DcVq.png)

While using Intercepting Routes, the first image shows it working well, but the second image shows it not functioning. What could be the reason for this discrepancy?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r111u.png)

(.) to match segments on the same level
(..) to match segments one level above
(..)(..) to match segments two levels above
(...) to match segments from the root app directory